# What does 欩 [chāo] mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, character-identification

Google translates 爷爷上山去欩柴。as, 'Grandad went up the mountain to get firewood.'.
Both Wiktionary and Chinesetools.com include this character, but give no meaning for it. I wondered if it were a rarely used classifier or an alternative character. (I am a beginner in Chinese.)

This is the first time that I have asked a question on Stack Exchange, so please bear with me.

Comment: From the [Kangxi](https://www.kangxizidian.com/kangxi/0566.gif) [Dictionary](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&id=331521): 欩：《集韻》敕宵切《集韻》癡宵切，音超。欩歊，氣上蒸。一曰健貌。

Comment: Was it from [*Momotaro*](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A1%83%E5%A4%AA%E9%83%8E)?

Comment: It was from 三王墓 [Sān Wáng Mù] - Tomb of the Three Kings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that I found this sentence in a childrens' storybook, it is more likely to be a misprint and should perhaps read '砍' [kǎn] - to chop?

Comment: this is extremely likely as 欩 does not even show in my dictionary.  At least in modern chinese it is unlikely to be used at all. Baidu shows the definition as a healthy appearance which wouldn't make sense in context anyway.

Comment: @zagrycha Try this online dictionary https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%AC%A9.

Comment: @r13 i've used zdic before they are great for rare terms.  in this case they match baidu definition exactly.

Comment: The combination 欩柴 is rare enough that *this very question* pops up as first result when searching for it on [startpage](https://www.startpage.com/do/search?q=%E6%AC%A9%E6%9F%B4&segment=startpage.vivaldi), so a misprint would seem likely.